# Python Class For Reading List Element ,__str__ and class questions

Tags: python, string, oop

I am writing a Python script which will ssh into a box(using parakimo) and run a command. I wanted to make a object for the stdout/stderr and print out the output.

1. Am I passing the list correctly into the class? and am I handing the
   list correctly in the class?
2. I want to utilize the `__str__` method so I can just print(object).
       How can I do this correctly?
3. I intend to use 2 instances of this class because I will be doing 2
       separate sss.exec_command(command). Am I wasting memory by wrapping
       this function in a class? I wanted to utilize the OO to be
       efficient, organized, and try to utilize python's OO features.

```
class read_log:
    def __init__(self, exit_status, *tuple_list):
        self.exit_status = exit_status
        self.tuple_list = tuple_list
        if exit_status:
            output = stderr.readlines()
        else:
            output =  stdout.readlines()
            del output[0]
            del output[-1]
    def __str__(self) 
        return ''.join(output)    

def create():
    stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("/home/one/script.sh")
    exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    x = readlog(exit_status, stdin, stdout, stderr)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capture the `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` inputs as *one* catch-all argument, but then try to refer to those names again in the `__init__` function.

Just make them separate parameters:

```
class read_log:
    def __init__(self, exit_status, stdin, stdout, stderr):
        self.exit_status = exit_status
        self.tuple_list = (stdin, stdout, stderr)
```

Use `*args` syntax when you need to allow for a variable number of arguments, not for catching a fixed number of arguments that you then otherwise not use. I stored the 3 arguments as a tuple onto your instance anyway, in case you are using `self.tuple_list` elsewhere.

You need to store `output` on the instance:

```
if exit_status:
    self.output = stderr.readlines()
else:
    self.output =  stdout.readlines()
    del self.output[0]
    del self.output[-1]
```

and in `__str__` refer to that instance attribute:

```
def __str__(self) 
    return ''.join(self.output)
```

The latter `del` statements can also be replaced with a slice:

```
if exit_status:
    self.output = stderr.readlines()
else:
    self.output =  stdout.readlines()[1:-1]
```

Comment: I keep getting <__main__.ReadLog instance at 0x7f39fd648878>. Why is this? By the way, I changed the class name to ReadLog instead of read_log. Also, what exactly is std* objects?

Comment: That is the `repr()` representation if your instance. Use `print` or `str()` to see your `__str__` method at work, or define a `__repr__` method to override the result of `repr()`.  The `std*` objects are file streams, the default ('standard' or 'std') input, output and error streams all processes on UNIX systems have.